# How can i send pdf file which is generated from my app and stored in local folder directly to a whatsapp number

Tags: android, pdf, share, whatsapp

I am developing a app which shares pdf file directly to a whatsapp number without selecting a number from list. That pdf file is generated via my app and i have stringFile, filepath and whatsapp number. How can i do it. I can share text directly to a number but not pdf

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+toNumber +"&attachment="+fileuri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please tell values of `fileUri.toString()` for txt and pdf file. Which app opens at startActivity executed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.